# Restart Actor after exception with previous state.

Tags: scala, akka, restore, kill, akka-supervision

Want to restart actor after exception with previous state by supervisor strategies.

For example

Actor supervisor saves some parameter from his children. Also supervisor has next strategy:

```
     override val supervisorStrategy =
            OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10) {

              case e : ActorKilledException     => {
                log.info("Restart === " + e)
                Restart

//TODO HOW TO SEND SOME PARAMETER TO THE ACTOR, AFTER RESTART ? 
              }
              case _: Exception                => Escalate
            }
```

How can I set previous parameter of actor "before crash" by  supervisorStrategy. ?

I could not find it by http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/general/supervision.html

Any links, examples  ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you think "keep previous state" you want the `Resume` strategy. Restart specifically means "give me a fresh Actor, without the (possibly) corrupted state".

It's documented in the page you're linking: "*Resume the subordinate, keeping its accumulated internal state*".